# How to identify string repetition throughout rows of a column in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, pattern-matching

I'm trying to think of a way to best handle this. If I have a data frame like this:

```
Module---|-Line Item---|---Formula-----------------------------------------|-repetition?|--What repeated--------------------------------|---Where repeated
Module 1-|Line Item 1--|---hello[SUM: hello2]------------------------------|----yes-----|--hello[SUM: hello2]---------------------------|---Module 1 Line item 2
Module 1-|Line Item 2--|---goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123] + hello[SUM: hello2]---|----yes-----|--hello[SUM: hello2], goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123]-|---Module 1 Line item 1, Module 2 Line Item 1
Module 2-|Line Item 1--|---goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123] + some other line item-|----yes-----|--goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123]---------------------|---Module 1 Line item 2
```

How would I go about setting up a search and find to locate and identify repetition in the middle or on edges or complete strings?

Sorry the formatting looks bad
Basically I have the module, line item, and formula columns filled in, but I need to figure out some sort of search function that I can apply to each of the last 3 columns. I'm not sure where to start with this.

I want to match any repetition that occurs between 3 or more words, including if for example a formula was `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` and that occurred 4 times in the Formula column, I'd want to give a yes to the boolean column "repetition" return `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` on the "Where repeated" column and a list of every module/line item combination where it occurred on the last column. I'm sure I can tweak it more to fit my needs once I get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was a bit messy, is surely some more straight forward way to do some of the steps, but it worked for your data.

Step 1: I just reset_index() (assuming index uses row numbers) to get row numbers into a column.

`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

I then wrote a for loop which aim was to check for each given value, if that value is at any place in the given column (using the `.str.contains()` function, and if so, where. And then store that information in a dictionary. Note that here I used `+` to split the various values you search by as that looked to be a valid separator in your dataset, but you can adjust this accordingly

```
#the dictionary will have a key containing row number and the value we searched for
#the value will contain the module and line item values
result = {}
#create a rownumber variable so we know where in the dataset we are
rownumber = -1
#now we just iterate over every row of the Formula series
for row in df['Formula']:
    rownumber +=1
    #and also every relevant value within that cell
    for value in row.split('+'):
        #we clean the value from trailing/preceding whitespace
        value = value.strip()
        #and then we return our key and value and update our dictionary
        key = 'row:|:'+str(rownumber)+':|:'+value
        value = (df.loc[((df.Formula.str.contains(value,regex=False))) & (df.index!=rownumber),['Module','Line Item']])
        result.update({key:value})
```

We can now unpack the dictionary into list, where we had a match:

```
where_raw = []
what_raw = []
rows_raw = []
for key,value in zip(result.keys(),result.values()):
    if 'Empty' in str(value):
        continue
    else:
        where_raw.append(list(value['Module']+' '+value['Line Item']))
        what_raw.append(key.split(':|:')[2])
        rows_raw.append(int(key.split(':|:')[1]))

tempdf = pd.DataFrame({'row':rows_raw,'where':where_raw,'what':what_raw})
```

`tempdf` now contains one row per match, however, we want to have one row per original row in the df, so we combine all matches for each main row into one

```
where = []
what = []
rows = []        

for row in tempdf.row.unique():
    where.append(list(tempdf.loc[tempdf.row==row,'where']))
    what.append(list(tempdf.loc[tempdf.row==row,'what']))
    rows.append(row)
result = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'index':rows,'where':where,'what':what}))
```

lastly we can now get the result by merging the result with our original dataframe

`result = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'index':rows,'where':where,'what':what}),how='left',on='index').drop('index',axis=1)`

and lastly we can add the `repeated` column like this:
`result['repeated'] = (result['what']!='')`

```
 print(result)
 Module     Line Item   Formula                                         what                                                 where
 Module 1   Line Item 1 hello[SUM: hello2]                              ['hello[SUM: hello2]']                               [['Module 1 Line Item 2']]
 Module 1   Line Item 2 goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123] + hello[SUM: hello2]   ['goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123]', 'hello[SUM: hello2]']   [['Module 2 Line Item 1'], ['Module 1 Line Item 1']]
 Module 2   Line Item 1 goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123] + some other line item ['goodbye[LOOKUP: blue123]']                         [['Module 1 Line Item 2']]
```